# Cast to char while toggline string case without using inbuilt functions

Tags: java

Here is the program i have written for converting case of string. However i am getting a compilation error as i have commented in the following program. Can you please explain to me in context of my code, what i am doing wrong?

```
public class Togg 
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String small="nayanjindalrocks";
    char a[]=new char[small.length()];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        a[i]=small.charAt(i);
        if(a[i]>='A'&&a[i]<='Z')
        {
        a[i]=a[i]+32; // Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to char (Add cast to char)
        }
        else
        {
            a[i]=a[i]-32; // Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to char (Add cast to char)
        }
    }
    String news=new String(a);
    System.out.print(news);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the compiler says, you're trying to assign an `int` value (the result of `a[i] + 32` for example to a `char` variable (`a[i]`). The "surprise" part here is that the result of `a[i] + 32` is a `char`... but it's only a surprise if you don't look at [JLS 15.18.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2), which specifies the `+` operator for numeric types, and which specifies that [binary numeric promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) is applied first. In this case, `a[i]` is implicitly promoted to `int` before the addition is performed.

Options:

- Add the cast, e.g.

  ```
  a[i] = (char) (a[i] + 32);
  ```
- Use `+=` or `-=` which performs the cast implicitly

  ```
  a[i] += 32;
  ```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (a[i] >= 'A' && a[i] <= 'Z') {
                a[i] = **(char)** (a[i] + 32); // Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to
                                    // char (Add cast to char)
            } else {
                a[i] = **(char)** (a[i] - 32); // Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to
                                    // char (Add cast to char)
            }
```

Here you are adding integer values to a[i], internally it will convert it to integer thats why you are getting compilation type mismatch error. You have explicitly cast it to char.